# Трансляция части экрана телефона

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Добрый день!

Передо мной стоит задача трансляция части экрана телефона на другой телефон. Я знаю что для записи экрана можно использовать `Android MediaProjection API` и `MediaProjectionManager`. Все примеры которые я видел захватывают весь экран телефона, но мне необходимо транслировать только `Fragment(Activity)` возможно ли для этого использовать `MediaProjectionManager` или есть другие способы?

Спасибо за помощь.